# Abortar por ajax un loop en el servidor c#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net

cómo están?
Tengo un problema que no se cómo resolverlo...espero puedan ayudarme.
Les cuento, por ajax hago un llamado al servidor que se queda en loop hasta que se pasa una tarjeta por un lector conectado por puerto com.
Si el usuario hace el llamado y pasa la tarjeta no hay problema, el problema ocurre cuando se hace el llamado por error y se desea cancelar el loop que queda en el servidor.
Probé con el abort() pero no me función, queda en cola hasta que da timeout en el servidor (por el loop)...
Espero haber sido lo más claro posible, gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto 
[Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), puede tratar de mejorar 
su pregunta mirando este link [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada, ya que no cumple con los estándares del sitio, no se lo tome a mal. Saludos

Comment: trata de poner código de ejemplo o algo verificable para que puedan ayudarte.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba agregando un CancellationToken a tu respuesta y generado un nuevo método que lo reciba como parámetro y desde ahí abortas tu tarea.

Algo como esto:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, CancellationTokenSource> 
            Tokens = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, CancellationTokenSource>();


        public ActionResult LoopLargo()
        {
            var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var token = source.Token;

            var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            Tokens.TryAdd(guid, source);

            var task = Task.Run(async () => {
                //Logica...
                await Task.Delay(10000);
            }, token);

        //Puedes agregar esto también en el cuerpo de la respuesta
        Response.Headers.Add("X-CancellationTokenId", guid.ToString());

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult DetenerTarea(Guid tokenId)
        {
            if (Tokens.TryGetValue(tokenId, out CancellationTokenSource source))
                source.Cancel();

            return Json("Tarea cancelada");

        }
    }
```

Mas información de cancelación de tareas:

https://geeks.ms/jorge/2017/09/22/usando-cancellationtoken-en-c/

Comment: Mira [answer], si bien el enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es bueno que coloques la parte esencial de la información aquí, ya que los enlaces en algún momento pueden estar rotos.